# Empty activity showing no screen on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I've just begun Android development and set up my Android Studio and Emulator up with minimum version of the project API as KitKat and maximum version as Oreo (8.0). I created an empty activity to start of with and wanted to test it out but when I run it I only get the following screen (it is literally transparent):

[image]

I've already changed my emulated performance graphics to Hardware - GLES 2.0. I've also tried cold booting and cancelling the saved state but to no avail. Here are the other AVD settings:

[image]

[image]

I would appreciate any help as I am very eager to get started. Thank you!

Comment: post your android manifest file code.

Comment: Try running app on real device or create new AVD & cross verify, what exactly causing problem. "Your app or emulator?"

Comment: Do you get any errors (or red tabs) in the 'logcat' logger window?

Answer (score 0):

Okay try to create a new virtual device.

And if then also it doesn't work then you can also run your application on your real device